# Spring boot APPLICATION FAILED TO START because Autowired bean not found

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My app:-

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan("fi.ma.vegshopping")
    @EnableJpaRepositories("fi.ma.vegshopping")
    @EntityScan(basePackages = "fi.ma.vegshopping")
    public class VegShoppingApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(VegShoppingApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

Problemict class:-

```
import fi.ma.vegshopping.dao.AccountDAO;
import fi.ma.vegshopping.entity.Account;

@Service
public class MyDBAuthenticationService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountDAO accountDAO;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Account account = accountDAO.findAccount(username); 
        System.out.println("Account= " + account);

        if (account == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " //
                    + username + " was not found in the database");
        }

        // EMPLOYEE,MANAGER,..
        String role = account.getUserRole();

        List<GrantedAuthority> grantList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        // ROLE_EMPLOYEE, ROLE_MANAGER
        GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role);

        grantList.add(authority);

        boolean enabled = account.isActive();
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;

        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) new User(account.getUserName(), //
                account.getPassword(), enabled, accountNonExpired, //
                credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, grantList);

        return userDetails;
    }

}
```

AccountDAO class:-

```
    package fi.ma.vegshopping.dao;

    import fi.ma.vegshopping.entity.Account;

    public interface AccountDAO {
        public Account findAccount(String userName ); 
    }
```

AccountDAOImpl class:-

```
    package fi.ma.vegshopping.impl;

    import javax.transaction.Transactional;

    import org.hibernate.Criteria;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

    import fi.ma.vegshopping.dao.AccountDAO;
    import fi.ma.vegshopping.entity.Account;


    @Transactional
    public class AccountDAOImpl implements AccountDAO {

        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        @Override
        public Account findAccount(String userName ) {
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Account.class);
            crit.add(Restrictions.eq("userName", userName));
            return (Account) crit.uniqueResult();
        }
    }
```

Error:-

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field accountDAO in fi.ma.vegshopping.authentication.MyDBAuthenticationService required a bean of type 'fi.ma.vegshopping.dao.AccountDAO' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'fi.ma.vegshopping.dao.AccountDAO' in your configuration.

Comment: Try add `@Repository` on your AccountDAOImpl.

Comment: I fail to see why you didn't understand the exception message. It clearly says that there is no Spring manage bean of type `AccountDAO` and you haven't added any anotation to the `AccountDAOImpl` class to make it one. Both exception and solution are pretty obvious.

Comment: I tried both @ Component and @ Repository in AccountDAOImpl class. Also I tried @ComponentScan("fi.ma.vegshopping.impl")
@ EnableJpaRepositories("fi.ma.vegshopping.impl")
@ EntityScan(basePackages = "fi.ma.vegshopping.impl") in VegShoppingApplication class. Nothing works. Still same error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be with the package structure and you need to mark `@Component` to your `AccountDAOImpl` class (which is under **`fi.ma.vegshopping.impl`** package) as shown below so that the container can scan & find your bean for injection.

```
@Component //or @Repository
public class AccountDAOImpl implements AccountDAO {
  //add your code here
}
```

Comment: I tried both @ Component and @ Repository in AccountDAOImpl class. Also I tried @ ComponentScan("fi.ma.vegshopping.impl")
@ EnableJpaRepositories("fi.ma.vegshopping.impl")
@ EntityScan(basePackages = "fi.ma.vegshopping.impl") in VegShoppingApplication class. Nothing works. Still same error.

Comment: AccountDAO should not extend for instance CrudRepository ?

Comment: If you are using spring-data jpa, you can